# Rotating collection objects together with python in blender 2.8

Tags: python, scripting, transforms

I created a character. The character has a body, skeleton and clothes. I want to rotate all of these object together.So far I have been able to select the objects in the collection. Below is what I have so far

```
col = bpy.data.collections.get("ManuelBastioni_Character")
if col:
   for obj in col.objects:
       obj.select_set(True)
```

I would like to do something like>>>>>>>

```
bpy.context.selected_objects.rotation_euler = (0,1,0)
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how you would do this in UI.  Eg default scene select all, 3d cursor as pivot point, and r to rotate, rotates all about the 3d cursor using the view vector as axis of rotation.

Comment: @batFINGER I ended up figuring it out. . But in the UI i would select the character armature and then press R and rotate it to my desired position. What I ended up doing is Armature.rotation_euler = (radians(90),0,0)